# How to encode the string within button_tag in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding

How to not escape the amp-encoded strings?

From:

```
= button_tag("&times;")
```

I get:

```
<button>&amp;times;</button>
```

But I want:

```
<button>&times;</button>
```

So it could render to:

```
×
```

How to do so?

## Update:

related to [ [Why does Rails 2.3.16 escape quote chars in form fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594815/why-does-rails-2-3-16-escape-quote-chars-in-form-fields?lq=1) ] but no clear answer, and a bit outdated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `html_safe` to disable automatic escaping of HTML entities:

```
= button_tag('&times;').html_safe
```